# Mutable parts of PE files in memory

Tags: pe, memory-dump

I currently try to figure out, what actually happens to a `PE File` in memory. To reword it: How could `PE files` differ, when they run on different computers and what are the mutable parts of a PE file, when they are loaded into memory?

My overall goal is to understand, what a **normalization process of memory dumps** of specific processes could look like (as mentioned [here](https://www.google.com/patents/US20090313700) for example).

**My understanding so far:**

- Sections getting mapped to different locations
- Sections get page-aligned
- IAT gets updated
- Base relocations are performed

Did I miss anything?

Comment: i think it talks about code that has equivalent operations what you mention are standard changes i think with normalization in that article it could mean  add eax , 1 = inc eax  is normalised?? as  plus()  or a plus() label is assigned when all equivalent instructions are met in a sequence well cant stand the legalese so just glanced around

Comment: I believe PE file format and how it works is excessively documented  https://www.google.com.au/search?q=pe+file+in+memory

Comment: As @blabb already mentioned, i try to figure out, how the normalization process is performed. Perhaps the "basic" normalization of PE loader based changes lead to confusion. Sorry!

Comment: the TLS section will have its index assigned